# upserting multiple object types in a single DML

Tags: apex

I have a case where i need to do an upsert of different sObjects, and I want to do them all at the same time. I know I can do a multiple records of a SINGLE sObject at the same time if I put them into an array and do an  upsert(array) . I was thinking In my case, cast the objects ( a master custom object, a detail custom object,and activities, all instantiated in apex) as sObjects and put them into an sObject array and then do an insert on that...  but as of now,that's all i've got...

ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't these Details need the id of the new Master? And Activities need their WhoId set. . .

Comment: you're right about the detail objects.... i guess, i should change the strategy to roll back the changes (update old records and delete new ones) if there is a failure.

Comment: That's what Database.setSavePoint and Database.rollback are for. Perhaps you should restate your question based on your prior comment. Regardless, I offer a solution for you, in case it helps.

Comment: i'll add this to the number of times you've helped me. thanks fox!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To roll back a partially failed transaction, you can use the following code:

```
System.savePoint sp = Database.setSavePoint();
try {
  // your logic here
} catch(exception e) {
  apexpages.addmessages(e);
  database.rollback(sp);
  return null; // assuming you're returning a value. Just return; otherwise.
}
// return a successful result, page reference, etc.
```

Answer (score 15):

You can actually upsert a `List` of `sObject` relatively easily. For instance, say you have 3 different custom objects, `Foo__c`, `Widget__c`, and `Stub__c`. You can add them to a list of `sObject` and upsert them together.

```
public static void dataSetup(){
   List<sObject> allObjects = new List<sObject>();
   allObjects.add(new Foo__c());
   allObjects.add(new Foo__c());
   allObjects.add(new Foo__c());
   allObjects.add(new Widget__c());
   allObjects.add(new Widget__c());
   allObjects.add(new Widget__c());
   allObjects.add(new Stub__c());
   allObjects.add(new Stub__c());
   allObjects.add(new Stub__c());
   upsert allObjects;
}
```

The only issue you will have is if you have relationships. The relationships require an Id on the original object to be able to link them together, so they must exist first.

I have [an article I wrote detailing this out further](http://jessealtman.com/2013/08/conserve-dml-statements/).